# Reflection - Dynamically converting an object to its SuperClass in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to convert an object of unknown type to its unknown superclass at runtime. I figured the best way to do this is by using reflection but it doesn't seem to be having the desired effect. Here is an example block of code where Laptop extends Device:

```
Laptop obj1 = new Laptop();
System.out.println(obj1.getClass().getName());

String className = obj1.getClass().getSuperclass().getName();
System.out.println(className);
    Object newObj;
    try {
        newObj = Class.forName(className).cast(obj1);
        System.out.println(newObj.getClass().getName());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So here I expect to see the following printed to the console:

```
package.Laptop
package.Device
package.Device
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
package.Laptop
package.Device
package.Laptop
```

Which indicates to me that obj1 is not getting converted to its parent type Device as I would expect it too?

Could anyone let me know what it is that I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This is by design.

Comment: Objects *are* always both of their subclass and their superclass at the same time. You cannot "convert" an object to its superclass. But the `getClass()` method always returns the deepest subclass of the object.

Comment: What is your purpose of converting to the super class? If you want to hide subclass methods/fields, you may use a decorator to hide them away.

Comment: `Class::forName` loads and initializes the class, but you got the name from an object of the class type, meaning that the class had _already_ loaded and initialized. Which means that your `forName` call has no effect. Why use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(There is a typo in your code. The third sysout tries to print obj which isn't declared in your code, I answer assuming you are trying to print newObj)

If you decompile and look at code of Class class, the cast method looks like this:

```
public T cast(Object arg0) {
    if (arg0 != null && !this.isInstance(arg0)) {
        throw new ClassCastException(this.cannotCastMsg(arg0));
    } else {
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

So effectively, your code is just this:

```
Object newObj = (Device) obj1;
System.out.println(newObj.getClass().getName());
```

Here, newObj is just a new reference to the same object obj1 which is already in memory. **All the calls to the methods on newObj will be the calls to the methods of obj1 which already exists in memory and is of type Laptop. So the getClass().getName() will return "Laptop".**